# How to parse json string using jsonpath?

Tags: json

I need to parse the json in example1 using jsonpath similar to the below example2. But could not find the path since the type of the json is string. Please suggest me some possible ways to parse the json string to modify the value for **colourCode** dynamically.

**Example1**:

```
{
    "payload": "{\"carBrand\":{\"model\":{\"colourCode\":2147483647}}}"
}
```

**Example2**:

```
{phone:{phoneType:"iPhone","cat":"11"}}
```

**Jsonpath**:

```
$.phone.phoneType
```

This will return "iPhone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with JsonPath library on its own. Here is an example:

```
String jsonString ="{\"phone\":{\"phoneType\":\"iPhone\",\"cat\":\"11\"}}";
String jsonExp = "$.phone.phoneType";
DocumentContext docCtx = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile(jsonExp);
String val1=docCtx.read(jsonPath);
System.out.println(val1); // print iPhone
```

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can refer to the documentation below for various other api's you can use.

```
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/blob/master/README.md
https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath
```

Comment: There is no JsonNode class in com.jayway.jsonpath. I can see only ValueNode.JsonNode. Is there anything I have to do?

Comment: @user3879701 Modified the answer and tested it locally as well. It should work for you

Comment: @user3879701 Actually that was a mistake, you don't need JsonNode. You can achieve your use case using normal JsonPath only. I have updated the code, please let me know if you face any issues. Thanks